# Denormalizing and querying a giant Couchbase data set

Tags: database, couchbase, database-performance, denormalization

Let's say I have about 1Tb of SQL email data that has the following fields:

`email, email_host, username, first_name, last_name, last_login`

I'm told that the MySQL queries like `SELECT * FROM emails WHERE email_host = 'gmail.com'` are running a bit slow... we're talking 30 minutes or more.

I'd like to try out Couchbase but I'm not sure how to go about denormalizing the data and building the `views`. It seems that one possible approach as per Couchbase's own video tutorial sessions is to create a "key," like:

`u::gmail::incremented_id`

or

`u::john::incremented_id`

then only fetch all the `u::gmail`s to have a list of keys corresponding to gmail addresses, instead of querying all of the documents and checking if the `email_host` attribute is `gmail`.

**Is this a legitimate / good strategy to go about denormalizing this sample data set and if so, what is the proper technique to create a view to preindex `u::whatever`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a map function like this:

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.type == 'user')
    emit(doc.email_host, doc);
}
```

Then you query the view using as key `gmail.com` to get all the users using gmail. If the database contains other document types, you better include a type attribute in your documents to distinguish different types.

Answer (score 0):

I would just add email_host to your document and give it the value behind the '@'. That way all documents have the email host as a field and can be easily queried. Should be high performing.

Comment: @dsp_099 Sorry, what are you specifically asking?